# Jquery dialog resizing only happens the first time it's opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this code for a JQuery a dialog for a div containing a gridview that loads with a lists of tasks. The dialog fits to the contents OK, but if hundreds of tasks are loaded the dialog gets too big and can't be resized by hand, so I needed to code a way for it to open with a manageable size.

Before anyone suggests it, **I tried setting the max-height property on my div to 500px** and that worked fine except the div wouldn't fill the whole dialog if the dialog got higher than 500px, which we want it to. **I also tried setting the maxHeight property on the dialog** directly but that only takes effect when you resize the dialog by hand, not when the dialog opens. And when the dialog opens bigger than the screen that can't be done.

So instead I wrote this code which declares the dialog, then if more than 20 tasks are loaded the dialog is supposed to be resized to 500px high. That way the div inside fills the dialog completely at all times and the dialog size stays managable.

```
function ShowReferedTasks(title, s, taskCount) {

    //On crée le dialog à partir de la même div       
    $('#litReferedTasks').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        show: 'drop',
        hide: 'drop',
        width: 800,
        minHeight: 0,
        title: 'Tâche' + s + ' référée' + s + ' de ' + title
    });

    //if more than 20 refered tasks are found
    if (taskCount > 20) {        
        $('#litReferedTasks').dialog('option', 'height', 500);
        $('#litReferedTasks').dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
    }
}
```

This code is called from a button in each line of a parent gridview, loading each line's tasks.

Here is what happens when I refresh my page and flush the cache (ctrl+F5), then open some task lists.

1. If I open one list of tasks containing more than 20 tasks (a dialog that will need to be refreshed), **it works fine**.
2. If I open any list of tasks, even one with less than 20 tasks that doesn't need resizing, then close it, and open one with more than 20 tasks, **the dialog opens and the gridview is filled perfectly but the resizing doesn't work**, the dialog is too big to fit on the screen, and can't be resized by hand.

Basically the resize part of my code only works on the first dialog I open after refreshing my page and flushing the cache. I think something must be kept in memory after the first time a dialog is opened, but I'm a newbie with JQuery and JS in general and I can't find the answer.

```html
<div id="litReferedTasks" style="background-color: White; display: none; overflow:auto; height:95%;">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvReferedTasks" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvReferedTasks_RowDataBound" Width="97.5%" Visible="false">        
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label ID="lblNoReferedTasks" runat="server" Visible="false" Width="100%"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Any help?

Comment: is your GridView inside an UpdatePanel?

Comment: @naveen you should note that while resizing doesn't work when opening a dialog for the 2nd time, the dialog still generates all the right data in the gridview every time it changes. That works fine.

Comment: could you show relevant portion of your html markup too?

Comment: have you verified that task count is correct each time the function is called?

Comment: @dqhendricks yes, the gridview is never wrong. The issue is only with the dialog resizing. My version was not solid next to yours, but it did work the first time. I still don't know why it would fail after that.

Comment: @naveen I added the div for the sake of information and completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so if you set the option after the dialog has been opened, height may not have an effect, but if you put height into the initial dialog creation code, it should have a set height just fine:

```
function ShowReferedTasks(title, s, taskCount) {

    var dialogOptions = {
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        show: 'drop',
        hide: 'drop',
        width: 800,
        minHeight: 0,
        title: 'Tâche' + s + ' référée' + s + ' de ' + title
    };

    //if more than 20 refered tasks are found
    if (taskCount > 20) {        
        dialogOptions.height = 500
    }

    //On crée le dialog à partir de la même div       
    $('#litReferedTasks').dialog(dialogOptions);
}
```

Comment: +1: very clean. but why doesn't `$('#litReferedTasks').dialog('option', 'height', 500);` work?

Comment: Thanks @dqhendricks, I'm trying that out, it looks good. But why would it work the first time then?

Comment: I tried out your solution and it works great, thanks. I'm not sure what you mean by creating a dynamic element though. How does `$('<div id="litReferedTasks"></div>').dialog();` link to the div I actually want to display? Does it just pick up the id in it and find the DOM element with that id?

Comment: @EplusL No, I guess what I meant basically is that it seems strange that you would be creating a dialog out of an element that is already attached to your DOM. Is #litReferedTasks visible on your page at all times, and then it turns into a dialog when they take a specific action? Typically if a dialog contains complex information, I usually fill it with html I receive from an AJAX call. Why load *all* the information on the first page load if they may only view one or two pieces of it? You could call the dialog content on demand with AJAX, and created a dialog out of it.

Comment: @dqhendricks I understand. But my div's gridview is invisible and made visible by the click event on the button that displays the dialog. The div is there but you just can't see it.

Comment: @dqhendricks actually the div is invisible as well (see the `display:none` attribute in the style property?). It doesn't even show up as a space or anything in the page. It's only displayed by the dialog.

Comment: It may be invisible, but it still has to be parsed and dealt with by the client. It would technically be better to avoid sending it to the client at all until it's needed, which is what they are suggesting. The "better" solution is usually to wait until they click the button, then fetch the HTML you need to display, rather than always sending it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are over-complicating the .dialog function. The easiest thing to do is create the dialog once with autoOpen set to false, rather than trying to re-initialize it every time. I think you'd have better luck with something like this:

```
// Do this once when the document is ready
$(function() {  
    $('#litReferedTasks').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: true,
    show: 'drop',
    hide: 'drop',
    width: 800,
    minHeight: 0
  });
});

function ShowReferedTasks(title, s, taskCount) {
    $('#litReferedTasks').dialog('option', 'title', 'Tâche' + s + ' référée' + s + ' de ' + title);
    if (taskCount > 20) {        
        $('#litReferedTasks').dialog('option', {
            height: 500,
            position: 'center'
        });
    }

    $('#litReferedTasks').dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: This is good, thanks. The other solution is cleaner though, and easier to tweak later.